# How to enable the use of <a> tag in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, eslint

I don't want to use `<Link>` from next. I've been researching how to disable this, but I can't.

I want to disable this and use the default html tag `<a>`.

It doesn't let me deploy, it keeps giving error because of that.

Can anyone help me?

The error I get:

> 12:9  Error: Do not use the HTML  tag to navigate to /. Use Link
> from 'next/link' instead. See:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-html-link-for-pages
> @next/next/no-html-link-for-pages

Comment: _"It doesn't let me deploy, it keeps giving error because of that"_ - what error does it give you during build? If it's the `@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages` rule it's complaining about, you can simply disable that ESLint rule.

Comment: that's exactly it, how do i disable it

Comment: Is it actually an error or just a warning? Could you please add the full error you're seeing to the question?

Comment: It is a error. I already added the question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can disable the `@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages` ESLint rule in your `.eslintrc` file.

```json
{
  // ...
  "rules": {
    // Other rules
    "@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages": "off"
  }
}
```

---

Note that the above is not recommended, as using `<a>` elements instead of the `next/link` component will disable client-side route transitions between pages. This means all pages will be loaded from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to navigate to home. You can try:
`<a href="https://(your app home path)">Home</a>`
Instead of:
`<a href="/">Home</a>`